Importing specific photos from file folder into Excel using VBA
I am trying to import pictures into Excel using VBA.  My current code allows the user to select the folder in which the pictures are located and then it imports all of the pictures from that folder into excel.  I would like to keep the folder selection process the same but only import selected photos.  The selected photos would be determined by the photo name in a column of my spreadsheet.  Below is my existing code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I do not want to have to insert the file path into the code.  I would like the user to select the folder the files are in and have the macro search that folder for the specific file names in column A and insert the corresponding pictures into excel.
Sub InsertPictures()

    Dim myDialog As FileDialog, myFolder As String, myFile As String
    
    Set myDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    If myDialog.Show = -1 Then
        myFolder = myDialog.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        myFile = Dir(myFolder)
        
        Do While myFile <> ""
        r = r + 2
        With Cells(r, 14)
            .RowHeight = 15
            x = .Left
            y = .Top
            w = .Width
            h = .Height
            
        End With
        
        myPicture = myFolder & myFile
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture (myPicture), _
        msoFalse, msoTrue, x, y, w, h
        myFile = Dir
        
        Loop
        
    End If
    
End Sub

'Code for word document with descriptions

Sub WordDocumentText()

    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        .Documents.Add
        
        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 10).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 12).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Text)
            .TypeText ". "
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Text)
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeParagraph
            
        End With
        
    End With
            
        
End Sub


When you have the folder you can use Dir(myFolder & picName) to see if there's a file named picName, where picName is a value from your list of filenames.

... or keep your existing loop but use Application.Match(myFile, listRangeHere, 0) to check if the file is in your list.

What do you mean by "The selected photos would be determined by the photo name in a column of my spreadsheet"? Which column of your sheet? Then, does the photo name contain the picture file extension? Don't you want that the imported picture to be placed on the same row with the picture name? Are the pictures in discussion square shapes (width = height)? If not, don't you need to not stretch them? To keep their aspect ratio...

You did not answer my clarification question, so I assume that you have the pictures name (without extension) in column picturesColumn ("C" in my code, change it according to your need):
Sub InsertPictures()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngPict As Range, rngP As Range, cel As Range
    Dim myDialog As FileDialog, myFolder As String, myFile As String, myPicture As String
    Dim x As Single, y As Single, W As Single, h As Single
    Const picturesColumn As String = "C" 'the column keeping the pictures name list
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet where you have the column/list of pictures name
    lastR = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, picturesColumn).End(xlUp).row 'last row on the column keeping pictures list
    Set rngPict = ws.Range(ws.cells(2, picturesColumn), ws.cells(lastR, picturesColumn)) 'the pictures range
    rngPict.EntireRow.RowHeight = 72 'set the whole range row height
    SetWidthHeightPoints 72, 72, rngPict.rows(1), 14  'set column (14) width equal to the rows height
    
    Set myDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With myDialog
       .Title = "Select the folder where from to pick up the necessary pictures"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'nothing has been selected...
       myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
    
    'Iterate between each cell of pictures range and insert if picture exists in myFolder:
    For Each cel In rngPict.cells
        myFile = Dir(myFolder & cel.value & "*") 'with or without extension in cel.value...
        If myFile <> "" Then
            Set rngP = ws.cells(cel.row, 14)
            x = rngP.left 'place the picture in column N:N
            y = rngP.top
            W = rngP.width
            h = rngP.height
            
            myPicture = myFolder & myFile
            ws.Shapes.AddPicture (myPicture), msoFalse, msoTrue, x, y, W, h
        End If
    Next cel
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Sub SetWidthHeightPoints(dWidth As Double, dHeight As Double, RW As Range, colNo As Long) 'transform column width in points...
    Dim COL As Range
    Set COL = ActiveSheet.Columns(colNo)
    
    Dim CNT As Long, lastWidth As Double
    
    RW.RowHeight = dHeight
    
    CNT = 0
    Do Until CNT = 10 Or COL.width = lastWidth
        lastWidth = COL.width
        COL.ColumnWidth = dWidth / COL.width * COL.ColumnWidth
        CNT = CNT + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Edited:
The next version keeps the dimensions ratio. It uses ws.Pictures.Insert(myPicture) and processes the necessary dimensions and location after inserting:

Sub InsertPicturesKeepRatio()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngPict As Range, rngP As Range, cel As Range
    Dim myDialog As FileDialog, myFolder As String, myFile As String, myPicture As String
    Dim x As Single, y As Single, W As Single, h As Single, pict As Object
    Const picturesColumn As String = "C" 'the column keeping the pictures name list
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet where you have the column/list of pictures name
    lastR = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, picturesColumn).End(xlUp).row 'last row on the column keeping pictures list
    Set rngPict = ws.Range(ws.cells(2, picturesColumn), ws.cells(lastR, picturesColumn)) 'the pictures range
    rngPict.EntireRow.RowHeight = 72 'set the whole range row height
    SetWidthHeightPoints 72, 72, rngPict.rows(1), 14 'set column (14) width equal with the rows height
    
    Set myDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With myDialog
       .Title = "Select the folder where from to pick up the necessary pictures"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'nothing has been selected...
       myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
       
    'Iterate between each cell of pictures range and insert if picture exists in myFolder:
    For Each cel In rngPict.cells
        myFile = Dir(myFolder & cel.value & "*") 'with or without extension in cel.value...
        If myFile <> "" Then
            Set rngP = ws.cells(cel.row, 14)
            x = rngP.left 'place the picture in column N:N
            y = rngP.top
            W = rngP.width
            h = rngP.height
            
            myPicture = myFolder & myFile
            Set pict = ws.Pictures.Insert(myPicture) 'it keeps dimensions ratio when change width or height!
             Dim ratio As Double: ratio = pict.width / pict.height
             
             If ratio > 0 Then 'width > height
               pict.left = x: pict.width = W
               pict.top = y + (h - pict.height) / 2
             ElseIf ratio < 0 Then
                pict.top = y: pict.height = h
                pict.left = x + (W - pict.width) / 2
             Else 'if they are equal
                pict.left = x: pict.top = y
             End If
        End If
    Next cel
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Use the same sub to set columns width equal with cells row height (in points).

@Kyle Anderson Didn't you find some time to test the above code(s)? If tested, didn't they do what you need?

Yes this worked perfectly thank you very much!  Is there a way to have the selected pictures added to a word document rather than the excel spreadsheet.  I already have a macro to create the word document input the descriptions for the photographs.  I have edited the post to include that macro.

@Kyle Anderson Almost everything is possible if you are able to do it manually. But I answered your question as it has been formulated! Why did you ask for Excel, then? You did not even answer my clarifications question. The way to do it is completely different. This should be another question. You do non even specify where the imported images to be placed. And I will leave my office in less than 5 minutes. If you place such a question and tag me here, showing the link, I will try helping after some hours, when I will be at home. If in the meantime somebody else will not answer it...

@Kyle Anderson Should I wait for other day to see the new question? Do you consider that my above code(s) did not answer your question? Editing it after receiving an answer is against the community rules and also not so fair...
